# Tangent line equation to $1/x$

Tags: calculus, functions

Determine the equation of the tangent to the graph of $f(x)=1/x$. $x$ cannot equal $0$ at the point where $x=a$.

I have tried subbing in $a$ for $x$ into the original equation then using the difference quotient equation to find the tangent I got the answer $\frac{((1/a+h)-(1-a))}h$. None of the answers I got in my trials gave me an answer that would seem to make sense. (no I do not have the actual answer)

Comment: Hi, welcome to this site. Please learn the basics of MathJax. It will make it so much easier for us to read

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** First, note your difference quotient has a typo. It should be
$\frac{\frac1{a+h}-\frac1a}{h}$, which can be rewritten as $\frac{-1}{a(a+h)}$.

Second, you must take the limit of the difference quotient as $h\to0$ to find the slope of the tangent line. If you don't take the limit, you don't have the tangent line at $(a,f(a))$, but only the approximating *secant* line between the points $(a,f(a))$ and $(a+h,f(a+h))$. So take the limit to get the slope.

Once you have the slope of the tangent line and the point $(a,f(a))$ of tangency on the graph, you can write an equation of the line tangent to the graph at that point by using point-slope form (recall it is $y-y_0 = m\cdot(x-x_0)$ where $m$ is the slope and $(x_0,y_0)$ is the point).

Note that everything will be in terms of the unspecified value $a$. You don't know what $a$ is, only that it is a value of $x$ for which there is a tangent to the graph.